# What is MVP award in IPL?

Tags: cricket, tournaments, awards, indian-premier-league

What is MVP award in IPL? How is it calculated?

I see the list of award leaders [from here](http://www.iplt20.com/stats/2013/pepsi-atom-mvp). But I can't understand how is it calculated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pepsi Atom Most Valuable Player Award is given to the player who contributes most to his team in all the areas like batting, bowling and fielding.

**The points added to the player for this award are:**
2.5 points will be given for each four
3.5 points will be given for each six
3.5 points will be given for each wicket taken
1 point for each dot ball bowled by a player
2.5 points for each catch or stumping taken by a player.

After adding all the points from the above aspects from every match, the total points for each player will be calculated. Referred the official source [here](http://www.iplt20.com/news/2013/more-news/3575/pepsi-atom-mvp-list).